# How to restrict strings in html input type text without setting type to number

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have this line of html code.

```
<input type="text"  minlength="12" maxlength="12" name="phone" placeholder="eg: 254700000000" required/>
```

I want it to accept only numbers.The reason I used type as text, is that I also want to use the *minlength and maxlength* attributes. How do I achieve this? Alternatively, how can I use input type number, and have the *minlength and maxlength* working?

Comment: Do you have an event handler in play, or is it just a form submit?

Comment: hmm maybe you can use check if the length of input value as an alternative to minlength and maxlength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a JS event handler on the `change` event of that input.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("the-input");


input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(input.value);
  
  if (!e.target.value.match(/^\d*$/)) {
    input.value = e.target.value.split('').filter(c => /\d/.test(c)).join('');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="the-input" type="text"  minlength="12" maxlength="12" name="phone" placeholder="eg: 254700000000" required/>
```

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as an answer. It doesn't validate at all.